# How to build the Livy client on Windows?

Tags: java, maven, apache-spark, livy

I want to write a Java app on Windows that uses Livy's Java API to talk to an  Apache Livy server that's hosted remotely. The [docs](https://github.com/apache/incubator-livy/blob/master/docs/programmatic-api.md#using-the-programmatic-api) say:

> Add the Livy client dependency to your application's POM:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.livy</groupId>
  <artifactId>livy-client-http</artifactId>
  <version>0.4.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
</dependency>
```

> Note: Until Livy's first Apache release you will have to install the
>   livy artifacts locally using `mvn install`

Unfortunately it looks like building Livy on Windows [isn't supported](https://groups.google.com/a/cloudera.org/d/msg/livy-user/1n3E83h92NA/3yT6oS1cAAAJ). Has anyone successfully built the Livy client on Windows?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All I cared about was getting livy-client-http to build and installed in my local maven .m2 repository. This is what I did in Windows 7:

`git clone` incubator-livy then comment out this section in its `pom.xml` (credit to [Yatzhash](https://groups.google.com/a/cloudera.org/d/msg/livy-user/1n3E83h92NA/p03HdFYQEQAJ)):

```
<requireOS>
    <family>unix</family>
</requireOS>
```

Run `mvn install -DskipTests` in the top level directory. If you do this from a regular Windows command prompt it will eventually fail with this error:

> [ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-antrun-plugin:1.8:run (default) on project livy-server: An Ant BuildException has occured: Execute
>    failed: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "bash" (in directory "C:\github.com\incubator-livy\server"): CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the
>   file specified
>   [ERROR] around Ant part ...... @ 4:27 in C:\github.com\incubator-livy\server\target\antrun\build-main.xml

But if you run the same command in a [Git Bash](https://git-for-windows.github.io/) prompt instead you can bypass this error. Eventually the build will fail at livy-integration-test but at least the livy-client-http build should have passed.

But you'll find this jar will have been installed in your .m2 repository: livy-client-http-0.4.0-incubating-SNAPSHOT.jar. This means you need to modify your own client app's dependency to look like this instead of the one recommended by the Livy docs:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.livy</groupId>
    <artifactId>livy-client-http</artifactId>
    <version>0.4.0-incubating-SNAPSHOT</version>
</dependency>
```

I also had to add this dependency to my client app because I wanted to talk to a Spark 2.1 server via Livy:

```
<dependency>
    <!-- See https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.0/programming-guide.html#linking-with-spark -->
    <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
    <artifactId>spark-core_2.11</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Then my client app would compile in Windows.